# Zend-Framework - view doesn't work

Tags: zend-framework, view, render

i'm makeing my 1st app whith Zend and i have got a problem.

**zftutorial.dev\application\controllers\IndexController.php**

```
<?php
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->title = "My Albums"; 
    }
}
```

**zftutorial.dev/application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->render('header.phtml'); ?>
<h1><?php echo $this->escape($this->title); ?></h1>
<?php echo $this->render('footer.phtml'); ?>
```

**zf-tutorial/application/views/scripts/header.phtml**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title><?php echo $this->escape($this->title); ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
```

**zf-tutorial/application/views/scripts/footer.phtml**

```
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

but when i go to address

> http://zftutorial.dev/

i get in my browser this info:

**An error occurred**

**Application error**

Offcourse i set up vhosts files and when i using

**zftutorial.dev/application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml**

```
<h1><?php echo $this->escape($this->title); ?></h1>
```

then everything is ok. Problem is whith this `<?php echo $this->render('header.phtml'); ?>` and this `<?php echo $this->render('footer.phtml'); ?>` line but i don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Where have you stored header.phtml and footer.phtml in your project?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Create the **header.php** and **footer.php** in the folder layouts/scripts/.

Then in your **layout.phtml** render the header and footer scripts.

**layout.phtml**

```
<html>
<head>
<?php echo $this -> headTitle(); //get the title ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $this->render('header.phtml'); //relative to layouts/scripts ?>
<?php echo $this->layout()->content; //the view script redered in the controller action?>
<?php echo $this->render('footer.phtml'); //relative to layouts/scripts ?>
</body>
```

**Bootstrap.php**

Add this function:

```
protected function _initViewHelpers() {
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');

    //Page Base Head Title
    $view -> headTitle('My Domain');
    //Page Head Title - Seperator
    $view -> headTitle() -> setSeparator(' - ');

    return $view;
}
```

**MyController.php**

Inside your **Controller Action** or inside the **init()** function, add the following line:

```
//Prepended - My Domain
$this->view->headTitle()->prepend('Prepended');

//My Domain - Appended
$this->view->headTitle()->append('Appended');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that use a layout is the better solution.

But with your code, you can do that:
In **zftutorial.dev/application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->partial('header.phtml', array('title' => $this->title)); ?>
<h1><?php echo $this->escape($this->title); ?></h1>
<?php echo $this->partial('footer.phtml'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your views aren't registered with ZF. Try registering them by placing the following method in your Bootstrap class.

```
   public function _initViewScripts(){
         $this->bootstrap ( 'view' );
         $view = $this->getResource('view');
         //Replace layout/scripts with the folder which contains your header.phtml and footer.phtml
         $view->addScriptPath (APPLICATION_PATH. '/layouts/scripts/');
   }
```

Also if you have placed the header and footer view inside `/application/views/scripts/index/` directory then move them to a higher directory like `/layouts/scripts/`